# Why doesn't 'Dir.exist?' work if a path starts with '~'?

Tags: ruby

I am confused with what's going on.

```
dir = "~/Downloads"
#=> "~/Downloads"

`ls #{dir}`
#=> "110912-font-awesome.zip\n"

Dir.exist? dir
#=> false
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you use `ls` you run a shell command and `~` is something shell-related (I suppose it's a shortcut for `$HOME` variable). But `Dir.exist?` is pure ruby, it knows nothing about the shell so that directory doesn't exist.

Anyway, this works

```
Dir.exist?(ENV['HOME'])
```

Answer (score 4):

[`File.expand_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-expand_path) can expand `~`:

```
dir = File.expand_path('~/Downloads')
#=> /home/stefan/Downloads

Dir.exist?(dir)
#=> true
```

Comment: @Ursus - this is probably what all ruby `File` and `Dir` functions should do for you if it isn't too much of a performance issue.